# Do I need to instantiate the XMLRPC class or any class in another class to access its methods?

Tags: customization, xml-rpc

I would like to use some of the methods of the XML RPC class, "wp_xmlrpc_server" in my own class. Is this class instantiated already or should I declare it myself? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far as I know, the XML RPC class is not instantiated unless needed, which is when the request is to [`/xmlrpc.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/xmlrpc.php).

You would instantiate the class the same way the Core does:

```
include_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php');
include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-IXR.php');
include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-xmlrpc-server.php');

/**
  * Posts submitted via the XML-RPC interface get that title
  * @name post_default_title
  * @var string
  */
$post_default_title = "";

/**
  * Filter the class used for handling XML-RPC requests.
  *
  * @since 3.1.0
  * @param string The name of the XML-RPC server class.
  */
$wp_xmlrpc_server_class = apply_filters( 'wp_xmlrpc_server_class', 'wp_xmlrpc_server' );
$wp_xmlrpc_server = new $wp_xmlrpc_server_class;
```

You have two options for doing that:

1. Create a method inside your class to instantiate the XML RPC class,
   and save the instance to a class variable.
2. Instantiate outside of the class and pass the instance to your
   class. This is something called "[dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)", which has both pros and cons.